# getting stated from previus activity

Tags: android, checkbox

I have 2 Activities, Activity_A and Activity_B 
Activity_A has a checkBox and a Button

what i am trying to do is when i click a Activity_A_button Activity_B would start 
Depending on Activity_A checkBox state a TextView is visible or Gone.

here is a sample code

```
        public class Main extends Activity {
    public static CheckBox check1;
        private Button Button1;

CheckBox check1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

final Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity_A.class);

    startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

Activity_B

```
 Textview1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

  if (Main.check1.isChecked())

        {
                  //code here

}
```

the problem is that i am getting a NullPointerExeption when i click Activity_A button @ the if statement

any ideas? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this.

send the value of the checkbox when calling the activity.then retrieve it from your second activity and work accordingly

```
final Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity_A.class);
    i.putExtras("value",""+check1.isChecked());//sending checked value to next activity
    startActivity(i);





Textview1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
 boolean ok=Boolean.parseBoolean(bundle.getString("value"));

  if (ok) //checkbox is checked in previous activity   
        {
               //code here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you didn't post everything (this code wouldn't compile), looks like you assigned check1 to a local variable

```
CheckBox check1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
```

instead of to your static class variable

```
public static CheckBox check1;
```

so `Main.check1` would still be null when you reference it in `Activity_B`. However regardless, this is still a bad way to share state between two activities as you are leaking an UI element. Why don't you instead submit the boolean value as a bundled extra that's part of the intent to start `Activity_B` or in the button listener set a static boolean variable? Both are much better and easier alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I also think it is corrected by passing intent from first activty to second activity.

```
final Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity_A.class);
i.putExtras("value",""+check1.isChecked());//sending checked value to next activity
startActivity(i);`
```

write this in first activity

```
Textview1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
boolean ok=Boolean.parseBoolean(bundle.getString("value"));

if (ok) //checkbox is checked in previous activity   
    {
           //code here
    }`
```

write this in second activity.